# Set operation in Graphiti.js

Tags: javascript

I am looking for set operation in Graphiti.js. I found one method `createSet()` which is a template method. I tried to use it, but I get an error message "canvas is undefined". How to use `createSet()` to create a set?

Answer (score 0):

the API for grouping shapes is only as internal API available (decoration to objects).

Sorry.

Comment: so is there any thing that can hold multiple objects inside ? e.g. rectangle holds another rectangle?